# An update operation that would target 0 rows, aborted by timeout

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have an update operation that is being executed on a quite large table (postgresql@10):

```
UPDATE contacts_trashbin 
SET op_id='\x60771801dbed2d6e021ec067'::bytea 
WHERE contacts_trashbin.company_id = '\x577f0cd198d4e67e170d31e1'::bytea 
  AND contacts_trashbin.deleted <= '2021-02-13T16:27:45.599860'::timestamp 
  AND (contacts_trashbin.op_id = '\x000000000000000000000000'::bytea 
       OR contacts_trashbin.removing IS true)
```

This request timeouts after 60 seconds (the hard limit we have on our server for all operations).
What's odd about this timeout is that the select with the same filter conditions:

```
select count(*) from contacts_trashbin
WHERE contacts_trashbin.company_id = '\x577f0cd198d4e67e170d31e1'::bytea
  AND contacts_trashbin.deleted <= '2021-02-13T16:27:45.599860'::timestamp
  AND (contacts_trashbin.op_id = '\x000000000000000000000000'::bytea OR contacts_trashbin.removing IS true)
```

takes only 71ms and returns `0`.

There are several indexes on this table, one of them is

```
    create index ix_company_id_deleted on contacts_trashbin (company_id, deleted);
```

The total number of rows `WHERE company_id='\x577f0cd198d4e67e170d31e1'` is ~600k if it matters.

Any ideas why it could be happening?

Comment: Try adding "FOR UPDATE" to your SELECT. If this hangs, investigate locks held on the table.

Comment: No, it doesn't hang. It expectedly selects nothing, and takes slightly more time (~150ms).

Comment: can you show the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for the the SELECT, and the plain EXPLAIN for the UPDATE?

Comment: Some table lock modes will block UPDATE, but not SELECT...FOR UPDATE.  So investigate table locks anyway.

Comment: @jjanes here is the explain https://explain.depesz.com/s/Nv3R. It seems that the estimate is way off, and PG tries to lock more rows than it should.